# WCF configuration works on localhost, not on shared website

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have an old ASP.NET website that has a WCF service that is used to return a JSON payload. It works fine in localhost, but when I try to deploy it to a **shared hosting website**, I get an exception:

> IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.

I cannot make this change as it is a shared environment.

Is there something I need to change in my configuration in `Web.config` with regards to the service? Here's what I've got:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="BoggleService">
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Solver" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttp">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I also had this configuration, but it was commented out (like I said, a project from long ago, trying to resurrect it):

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://www.example.com/"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

But if I uncomment that and include it, I get the following exception in *both* localhost and in the shared hosting website:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource) +64
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +15
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +7515544
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost host, IDictionary`2 implementedContracts, String multipleContractsErrorMessage) +82
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening() +203
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +229
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +121
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +479

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Solver.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.]
   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +11667006
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +194
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +176
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +275
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

And this is coming from within the bowels of WCF - it's not coming from my code (the stack trace shows it never gets to my code and if I run the debugger and set a breakpoint in my code, it is never reached).

And interestingly, if I set the `<baseAddressPrefixFilters>` setting to `http://localhost`, it works on localhost! But not on production.

Thanks!

Comment: That exception doesn't seem related to WCF. Are you sure there is nothing else in your web.config?

Comment: I updated my post with the Stack Trace and added the detail that if I set the `<baseAddressPrefixFilters>` setting to `http://localhost`, it works on localhost! But not on production. Could this be some issue with changes in the .NET Framework version? I started this project many moons ago on .NET 2.0 and now it's being hosted on 4.x. Has the configuration syntax changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be simplified given that it uses the WebHttpBinding to host Restful style service.
In .net4.5, we could use the following simplified configuration to host the Restful style service.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

By default, the webhttpbinding use WebHttpSecurityMode.None. So it is unlikely that the authentication schema error above will occur. If necessary, don't forget to enable the authentication mode in IIS authentication module.
Try to replace your configuration with mine and provide a http binding in IIS site binding module.
Feel free to let me know If there is anything I can help with.